MySql for Visual Studio 2022
I am having problems in Visual Studio 2022 Profesional with MySQL. Maybe, anyone can help me because someone was in the same situation.
I installed:

MySQL Connector 8.0.25
MySQl for Visual Studio (last version 2.0.5)

And I get this screen yet:

No Mysql Provider
What Can I do?

You didn't explain what the problem is. Applications don't use the Visual Studio extension, they use the provider added as a NuGet package. Oracle discontinued the VS extension 7 years ago and frankly, it didn't help at all. In fact, Oracle's Connector/.NET is so buggy and badly maintained that more people use the truly open source MySqlConnector provider

The screenshot doesn't show any extensions either, it only shows the .NET Framework providers installed in the machine's GAC. Even .NET applications don't work that way since at least 2012 though. Database providers (and even parts of .NET itself) are added as NuGet packages. Even the SQL Server provider is added through the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package or its predecessor, System.Data.SqlClient.
